# Convert a string reference to variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to soft code the output variables, so that I don't have to modify the VBA code each time i need to modify the outputs.

**This is the code that works**

```
Sub Working()
    Dim cat(1 To 10)
    Dim bat(1 To 10)

    For i = 1 To 10
        cat(i) = i * 10
        bat(i) = i * 5
    Next i

    Sheet2.Range("A2:A11") = Application.Transpose(cat())
    Sheet2.Range("B2:B11") = Application.Transpose(bat())
End Sub
```

**This is the ideal way i would want to write, but doesnt work**

```
Sub not_working()
    Dim cat(1 To 10)
    Dim bat(1 To 10)

    For i = 1 To 10
        cat(i) = i * 10
        bat(i) = i * 5
    Next i

    a = 3
    Do While Sheet1.Cells(a, 1) <> ""
        OutVar = Sheet1.cells(a, 1) & "()" 
        Sheet3.Range( _
            Cells(2, a - 2).Address, Cells(11, a - 2).Address _
        ) = Application.Transpose(Outvar)
        a = a + 1
    Loop
End Sub

' Sheet1.cells(3,1) = cat - these cells contain the variable names
' Sheet1.cells(4,1) = bat - these cells contain the variable names
```

Can someone please suggest if it is possible to do so?

Comment: You title says converting `String reference` to `variable name`. Are you referring to a String array by String reference? You code is just outputing an array to a sheet via `Transpose`. Can you explain the issue please?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There are two pieces of code above, "sub working"  and "sub not_working". The code in the procedure "working" is fine except that the output variables( cat & bat) are hard coded in the code. I would want to refer to the output variables as I have done in procedure "not_working". The names of the output variables can be called as string reference. my issue is to make the code understand that it is am array variable I am referring to...

Comment: I share bonCodigo's confusion because when I was in support this was the most difficult type of question.  You are telling us the technology you want to exist; you are not telling us why you want to use that technology.  I like to hold parameters in a worksheet that tell my program that today I want this data moved to there.  In both versions you hard code the creation of two arrays; only the destination is to vary.  Do you expect to add a third and a fourth array?  What are the future requirements you expect and would like to prepare for?

Comment: Hi Tony, I was unaware that vba is not capable of doing this. I merely wanted to check if it is possible. I am sorry i didnt state this earlier, the above is only a sample code and the actual code which i use has about 200-300 variables. Moreover the output requirement is also not fixed. I would want to soft code the output requirement so that i can reduce changes to the code. You are right, in both cases the creation of arrays is hard coded, but i need to be able to soft code the array to be output and obviously the destination. It is extremely ineeficient to output all variables.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, a ragged array will meet it.

If you have a variable of type Variant, you can set that variable to, for example, an integer, a real, a string, a boolean or an array.

If you have an array of type Variant, you can set each element of that array to a different type of value.

In my code below, I have variant array Main.  I set:

- Main(0) to a 1D array,
- Main(1) to a larger 1D array,
- Main(2) to a 2D array,
- Main(3) to a single integer,
- Main(4) to the used range of a worksheet.

This is called a ragged array because each element is a different size.

Having loaded the array with values,  I use a general routine to output each element of Main according to its nature.

Each of your 200-300 variables would become an element of Main.

Have a look at my code.  This is only a brief introduction to what can be achieved with variant arrays.  Come back with questions if you think I am heading in the correct direction but have not gone far enough.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DemoRaggedArray()

  Dim InxDim As Long
  Dim InxMain As Long
  Dim InxWCol As Long
  Dim InxWRow As Long
  Dim Main() As Variant
  Dim NumOfDim As Long
  Dim Work() As Variant

  ReDim Main(0 To 5)

  Work = Array(1, "A", True)

  Main(0) = Work

  Main(1) = Array(2, "B", False, 1.2)

  ReDim Work(1 To 2, 1 To 3)

  Work(1, 1) = 1
  Work(1, 2) = 2.5
  Work(1, 3) = DateSerial(2012, 12, 27)
  Work(2, 1) = True
  Work(2, 2) = "String"

  Main(2) = Work

  Main(3) = 27

  ' Cells A1:C4 of the worksheet have been set to their addresses
  Main(4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Value)

  For InxMain = LBound(Main) To UBound(Main)
    Debug.Print "Type of Main(" & InxMain & ") is " & VarTypeName(Main(InxMain))
    Select Case VarType(Main(InxMain))
      Case vbEmpty, vbNull
        ' No value
      Case Is >= vbArray
        ' Array
        NumOfDim = NumDim(Main(InxMain))
        Debug.Print "  Main(" & InxMain & ") is dimensioned as: (";
        For InxDim = 1 To NumOfDim
          Debug.Print LBound(Main(InxMain), InxDim) & " To " & _
                                                  UBound(Main(InxMain), InxDim);
          If InxDim < NumOfDim Then
            Debug.Print ", ";
          End If
        Next
        Debug.Print ")"
        Select Case NumOfDim
          Case 1
            For InxWCol = LBound(Main(InxMain)) To UBound(Main(InxMain))
              Debug.Print "  (" & InxWCol & ")[" & _
                                        VarTypeName(Main(InxMain)(InxWCol)) & "]";
              Select Case VarType(Main(InxMain)(InxWCol))
                Case vbEmpty, vbNull, vbArray
                  ' No code to handle these types
                Case Else
                  Debug.Print "=" & Main(InxMain)(InxWCol);
              End Select
            Next
            Debug.Print
          Case 2
            For InxWRow = LBound(Main(InxMain), 2) To UBound(Main(InxMain), 2)
              For InxWCol = LBound(Main(InxMain), 1) To UBound(Main(InxMain), 1)

                Debug.Print "  (" & InxWCol & "," & InxWRow & ")[" & _
                             VarTypeName(Main(InxMain)(InxWCol, InxWRow)) & "]";
                Select Case VarType(Main(InxMain)(InxWCol, InxWRow))
                  Case vbEmpty, vbNull, vbArray
                    ' No code to handle these types
                  Case Else
                    Debug.Print "=" & Main(InxMain)(InxWCol, InxWRow);
                End Select
              Next
              Debug.Print
            Next
          Case Else
            Debug.Print "  There is no display code for this number of dimensions"
        End Select
      Case Else
        ' Single variable
        Debug.Print "  Value = " & Main(InxMain)
    End Select
  Next

End Sub
Public Function NumDim(ParamArray TestArray() As Variant) As Integer

  ' Returns the number of dimensions of TestArray.

  ' If there is an official way of determining the number of dimensions, I cannot find it.

  ' This routine tests for dimension 1, 2, 3 and so on until it get a failure.
  ' By trapping that failure it can determine the last test that did not fail.

  ' Coded June 2010. Documentation added July 2010.

  ' *  TestArray() is a ParamArray because it allows the passing of arrays of any type.
  ' *  The array to be tested in not TestArray but TestArray(LBound(TestArray)).
  ' *  The routine does not validate that TestArray(LBound(TestArray)) is an array.  If
  '    it is not an array, the routine return 0.
  ' *  The routine does not check for more than one parameter.  If the call was
  '    NumDim(MyArray1, MyArray2), it would ignore MyArray2.

  Dim TestDim                   As Integer
  Dim TestResult                As Integer

  On Error GoTo Finish

  TestDim = 1
  Do While True
    TestResult = LBound(TestArray(LBound(TestArray)), TestDim)
    TestDim = TestDim + 1
  Loop

Finish:

  NumDim = TestDim - 1

End Function
Function VarTypeName(Var As Variant)

  Dim Name As String
  Dim TypeOfVar As Long

  TypeOfVar = VarType(Var)

  If TypeOfVar >= vbArray Then
    Name = "Array of type "
    TypeOfVar = TypeOfVar - vbArray
  Else
    Name = ""
  End If

  Select Case TypeOfVar
    Case vbEmpty
      Name = Name & "Uninitialised"
    Case vbNull
      Name = Name & "Contains no valid data"
    Case vbInteger
      Name = Name & "Integer"
    Case vbLong
      Name = Name & "Long integer"
    Case vbSingle
      Name = Name & "Single-precision floating-point number"
    Case vbDouble
      Name = Name & "Double-precision floating-point number"
    Case vbCurrency
      Name = Name & "Currency"
    Case vbDate
      Name = Name & "Date"
    Case vbString
      Name = Name & "String"
    Case vbObject
      Name = Name & "Object"
    Case vbError
      Name = Name & "Error"
    Case vbBoolean
      Name = Name & "Boolean"
    Case vbVariant
      Name = Name & "Variant"
    Case vbDataObject
      Name = Name & "Data access object"
    Case vbDecimal
      Name = Name & "Decimal"
    Case vbByte
      Name = Name & "Byte"
    Case vbUserDefinedType
      Name = Name & "Variants that contain user-defined types"
    Case Else
      Name = Name & "Unknown type " & TypeOfVar
  End Select

  VarTypeName = Name

End Function
```

Output from *DemoRaggedArray*

```
Type of Main(0) is Array of type Variant
  Main(0) is dimensioned as: (0 To 2)
  (0)[Integer]=1  (1)[String]=A  (2)[Boolean]=True
Type of Main(1) is Array of type Variant
  Main(1) is dimensioned as: (0 To 3)
  (0)[Integer]=2  (1)[String]=B  (2)[Boolean]=False  (3)[Double-precision floating-point number]=1.2
Type of Main(2) is Array of type Variant
  Main(2) is dimensioned as: (1 To 2, 1 To 3)
  (1,1)[Integer]=1  (2,1)[Boolean]=True
  (1,2)[Double-precision floating-point number]=2.5  (2,2)[String]=String
  (1,3)[Date]=27/12/2012  (2,3)[Uninitialised]
Type of Main(3) is Integer
  Value = 27
Type of Main(4) is Array of type Variant
  Main(4) is dimensioned as: (1 To 3, 1 To 4)
  (1,1)[String]=A1  (2,1)[String]=B1  (3,1)[String]=C1
  (1,2)[String]=A2  (2,2)[String]=B2  (3,2)[String]=C2
  (1,3)[String]=A3  (2,3)[String]=B3  (3,3)[String]=C3
  (1,4)[String]=A4  (2,4)[String]=B4  (3,4)[String]=C4
Type of Main(5) is Uninitialised
```

Note the date is displayed as "27/12/2012" because that is the default date format for my country.  If you run this code, it will display in your country's default format.